# Figuring out Aに助かりました

Tags: particles

Does Aに助かりました mean that you were saved from A, or you were saved by A?

Comment: I think your expression is ungrammatical unless `Aに` is something not directly related to the predicate. It does not mean either of what you suggest.

Comment: So how do you say 1) you were saved from something and 2) you were saved by something?

Comment: @languagae_hacker 1) `...から助けられました` or `...から助かりました` 2) `...に助けられました`

Comment: Did you randomly come up with the sentence, or did you happen to pick it up somewhere in a native literature?

Answer (score 2):

助かる is an intransitive verb which means "to be saved".

Aに助かりました would mean "At the point of time/space of A, you were saved.(No agent is implied in the statement. It just means you were saved)"

Much like 窓が開く, it would mean "the window opens" without implying any agent.

Then consider ３時に窓が開く, it would mean "the window opens at 3 o'clock"

(Agent: one who initiates and/or completes an action or event)

Comment: I suppose it means に can't be used to point at the agent for this particular verb.