# Passive + Noun. Who did what?

Tags: passive-voice

Here's an example:

みなさんに愛される人。

Does this mean, "the person that everyone loves," or "the person that loves everybody?"

Comment: Babylon translates it as "The person who is loved by all of you" ;)

Comment: Also, you should already be able to translate に+passive pattern since you already asked [a similar question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2283/figuring-out-a%e3%81%ab%e5%8a%a9%e3%81%8b%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f) and got the answer from sawa's comment there. `X+に+passive` is simply `is <passiveverb> by X`.

Comment: It's not clear. X+に+passive = passive X?

Answer (score 6):

`The person that is loved by everyone.`

It's just a basic relative clause, no magic involved.

Comment: I'm curious as to why the English passive never made its way into the translations in the question...

Comment: @Hyperworm Probably because active verbs sound more natural in English and the meaning is the same anyway.

Comment: @Chris true, but only if you can get the subject and object the right way around when converting from passive to active, which seems to have been the OP's difficulty. Solution: don't skip steps: we explicitly state that `the person` is loved, and therefore it's `everyone` who loves.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Ah, fair enough. I used to get the subject and object mixed up in phrases that used the verb 含まれる, too. Still, once you're proficient enough in the language, I think that it makes more sense to replace passive verbs with active verbs whenever possible.